# What is the correct way to resolve type issues in typescript

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Example:

```
// Types:
type TCountryCode = 'US' | 'RU' | 'KZ' | 'UA'
function doSomethingWithCountryCode(countryCode: TCountryCode): void => { ... }

// Code:
let countyCodes = ['US', 'RU', 'KZ', 'UA']
for (let countryCode of countryCodes) {
    doSomethingWithCountryCode(countryCode)
}
```

But Typescript compiler says, I can't pass "string" instead of "TCountryCode" type to the function.

My solution is:

```
let countyCodes = <('US' | 'RU' | 'KZ' | 'UA')[]>['US', 'RU', 'KZ', 'UA']
```

Or:

```
let countyCodes = ['US', 'RU', 'KZ', 'UA'] as ('US' | 'RU' | 'KZ' | 'UA')[]
```

But it doesn't seem to to be right because it looks too bad and long

What is the correct way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Since you're already defining a Country Code type, you could use `countryCodes: TCountryCode[] = ['US', 'RU', 'KZ', 'UA'];`

Comment: @ExplosionPills the reason I didn't use this way: "countyCode" type is part of other large structure and I dropped it to ask a question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `countyCodes` as `const` so it doesn't get automatically type-widened:

```
const countyCodes = ['US', 'RU', 'KZ', 'UA'] as const;
```

You can also use the above expression to define the type, if you want, to make things even less repetitive:

```
type TCountryCode = typeof countyCodes[number];
```

Comment: "as const" is what I was needed. Thank you